# How to reduce size of a plot, keeping numbers axis the same?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a histogram plot with `matplotlib`, but the histogram occupies all space on the plot, I would like to add more space around. How can I scale down the histogram, but keep number on the axis the same size?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_adjust.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you change the xlimits? try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.hist(data)

vmin = data.min().min()
vmax = data.max().max()
data_range = vmax - vmin
scale_factor = 0.1
xmin = vmin - scale_factor*vmax
xmax = vmax + scale_factor*vmax
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
```